# With Jsoup, is possible get elements from two selectors with one select?

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to get the links from a page in the `href`or `src` attributes. I can do:

```
Elements href = doc.select("[href]");
Elements src = doc.select("[src]");
```

There is a way to get links that matches the two attributes: Something like:

```
Elements links = doc.select("[href] OR [src]");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Elements links = doc.select("[href], [src]");
```

That should work.

Edit: more explanation can be found in the online cookbook, particularly in the subsection "Selector combinations"

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: Thank you. I saw the documentation, but I was with doubts about the right way.